# Find supremum and infimum of set 3

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, supremum-and-infimum

Find the supremum and infimum and study if those are maximum or minimum of this set $\left \{ x \in \mathbb{R}: x^{2} \leq 3 \right \}$

Now, this i was thought about this set:

$\sqrt3$ is an upper bound of $\left \{ x \in \mathbb{R}: x^{2} \leq 3 \right \}$
. Thus $\text{sup(S)} \leq \sqrt3$, but $\sqrt3 \in \left \{ x \in \mathbb{R}: x^{2} \leq 3 \right \}$, so $Sup=\sqrt3$ and maximum as well. 
Am i wrong?

Comment: looks correct to me

Comment: Your are fine..I would also recommend as an nice exercise to you to prove that the supremum of $A=\{x \in \mathbb{Q}|x^2<3\}$ is $\sqrt{3}$

Comment: I concluded this set doesn't have infimum so it doesnt have minimum either  am i right?

Comment: @MariosGretsas Your comment could be a nice answer.

Comment: @TheNicouU If you're speaking about your set then no it has an infimum.

Comment: Thanks @Scientifica ..its ok it don't have to be..The necessary part is for the O.P to practise this exercise and if he wants to post it to a new question with his attempts also..

Comment: Im going to prove it for $\Bbb Q $. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x^2\le 3 \iff (x-\sqrt {3})(x+\sqrt {3})\le 0$$

$$\iff -\sqrt {3}\le x \le \sqrt {3} $$

$$\iff x\in [-\sqrt {3},\sqrt {3}] .$$

thus, the minimum is $-\sqrt {3} $ and the maximum is $\sqrt {3} $.

> Remark

This is not true in $\Bbb Q $.